# How to get current bean name/id to use it inside bean initialization for building placeholder name

Tags: java, spring

Hi Spring Framework experts!

I need to make 10+ of similar beans configurable with using placeholders. The only difference between them is unique placeholder keys (`${bean1.key}`, `${bean2.key}` and so on). If I do it straight, I should copy bean definition 10+ times and change only first part of placeholder. So I'm thinking how to avoid this duplication.

I would like to generate placeholder string dynamically. As dynamic part I would like to use current bean `ID` (or alternatively it's field value).
It should be something like this.

```
<!-- Template -->
<bean id="mainProfile" abstract="true" class="com.company.SomeClass">
    <property name="role" value="${${this.beanName}.role:NA}">
    <!-- other properties initialized in same way -->
</bean>
<!-- Instances -->
<bean id="profile1" parent="mainProfile"/>
<bean id="profile2" parent="mainProfile"/>
<bean id="profile3" parent="mainProfile"/>
```

As result, property `role` for all beans can be initialized by adding next lines to the `app.properties`:

```
profile1.role=admin
profile2.role=guest
profile3.role=editor
```

I've tried next approaches:

1. [BeanNameAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html) + SpEL

Unfortunately, `bean name` is `null` before bean initialization. I believe this approach may work only if bean name can be provided by Spring out of the box and it has predefined placeholder. Am I right? Does Spring have such system variables?

2. `Factory` for constructing placeholder names dynamically.

As for me it can be used for generating values, but not placeholders names.

I would appreciate for any advices!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
<!-- Template -->
<bean id="mainProfile" abstract="true" class="com.company.SomeClass">
    <!-- other properties initialized in same way -->
</bean>

<!-- Instances -->
<bean id="profile1" parent="mainProfile">
    <property name="role" value="${profile1.role}">
</bean>
<bean id="profile2" parent="mainProfile">
    <property name="role" value="${profile.role}">
</bean>
<bean id="profile3" parent="mainProfile">
    <property name="role" value="${profile3.role}">
</bean>
```

Comment: This is how it currently works. Real bean has a lot of fields, let's think 15. So I should configure manually 10*15=150 placeholders. Beans amount is increasing to meet client's needs. After one year, it may be 50 beans and bean structure may be changed a bit (for example, 3 fields will be added). So I will have to support 50*18=900 placeholders. This is a main reason why I would like to automate placeholder name generation. And additionally this change will reduce my XML file and will make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to declare your beans programmatically instead of using XML.

You could use [`GenericBeanDefinition`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/GenericBeanDefinition.html) class to define your object in a way like this:

```
GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
beanDef.setBeanClass(com.company.SomeClass);

MutablePropertyValues values = new MutablePropertyValues();
values.addPropertyValue("name", beanName);
values.addPropertyValue("role", role);

beanDefinition.setPropertyValues(values);
```

Using this piece of code inside a loop you could retrieve `beanName` and `role` from your properties.

Comment: Thank you, davioooh! This may work. I'll check it today. It's pity what I can't vote up this answer, but I'll do it after getting needed reputation.

Comment: Unfortunately _GenericBeanDefinition_ didn't help, because it doesn't support placeholders like _${bean.key}_ and sets them as simple string values.